# Trigger gives an error on multiple Rows Update in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a problem when i create a trigger that works fine on one row but when I apply it on multiple rows it giving me this error

> This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

The trigger is :

```
Create TRIGGER AccountChange
ON Customer
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF(UPDATE(TotalSales))
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @TotalSales MONEY, @AccountNumber NVARCHAR(20),
                @TotalSalesOld MONEY, @customText1 NVARCHAR(50),
                @AccountTypeId int

        SET @TotalSales = (SELECT TotalSales FROM INSERTED)
        SET @TotalSalesOld = (SELECT TotalSales FROM DELETED)
        SET @AccountNumber = (SELECT AccountNumber FROM INSERTED)
        SET @AccountTypeId = (SELECT AccountTypeId FROM INSERTED)

        IF(@TotalSales BETWEEN 0 AND 5000)
           UPDATE Customer 
           SET AccountTypeID = 8 
           WHERE AccountNumber = @AccountNumber
   END
END
```

I just want it to work with any number of inserted rows considering that I'm having a scheduled connection that have multiple insertion/update everytime.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your trigger **MAJOR** flaw is that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT TotalSales FROM INSERTED` - it's non-deterministic. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trigger should look like this to handle `UPDATE` with multiple affected rows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AccountChange
ON dbo.Customer
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.Customer 
    SET AccountTypeID = 8 
    FROM Inserted i
    INNER JOIN Deleted d ON i.AccountId = d.AccountId  -- use the primary key here
    WHERE AccountNumber = i.AccountNumber
      AND i.TotalSales BETWEEN 0 AND 5000
      AND i.TotalSales <> d.TotalSales  -- TotalSales was updated
      AND dbo.Customer.AccountId = i.AccountId   -- use the PK here
END
```

One single, pretty simple and straightforward set-based statement - and that's all there is!